# How to refer to a value if you have the depth of the tuple when you can't use the index of a nested tuple explicitly?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tuples

Let's say there is a tuple in the form

```
    J = ((1),((2),((3),((4), (7,7)))))
```

and you want to change the value of a index of J depending on how many iterations have occurred within a for loop.

The problem involves replacing the second tuple with an integer, but because of the for loop each time the depth being referred to will be different.

Objective:
does an operation using values within a tuple and to replace that tuple with the value

I know that

```
    list(J)[1][1][1][1]
```

will be equal to the (7,7) the value that I want to change.

But say I have the depth of the index - 4. Is there a way to have that as a variable and code to refer to

```
    list(J)[1][1][1][1]
```

by using 4 instead of having to type out each bracket, in a hardcoded way?
Reason being, I want to include the assignment within a for loop.

i.e. something like

```
    list(J)"[1]"*depthvariable = changed value
```

or something, which will be equal to

```
    list(J)[1][1][1][1] = changed value
```

when depthvariable is equal to 4?

In short, is there a way to use integers that will be incremented each time so that within the code itself it can do this:

for 1 time :

```
    J[1]
```

for 2 time:

```
    J[1][1]
```

for 3 time:

```
    J[1][1][1]
```

If I use for jelement in J, then I lose the overall variable. I'm not trying to get elements within the J tuple, and I need to keep the overall variable. I'm just trying to change certain elements within J, but I'm not sure how to code if the depth I'm looking at is different each time within a for loop.

The part I'm really struggling with is finding an expression to refer to an element in the tuple when the depth changes each time.
Because it will involve having a different number of brackets.
E.g.

```
    J[1], J[1][1] etc.
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:
It's important that I can change J itself using the variable depth index.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop.

```
J = ((1),((2),((3),((4), (7,7)))))
cur = J
depthvariable = 4
for _ in range(depthvariable):
    cur = cur[1]
print(cur)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `operator.getitem`.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

J = ((1),((2),((3),((4), (7,7)))))

print(reduce(getitem, [1] * 4, J))
```